# content_shell crashes when running in Win7 x64

Tags: unit-testing, automation, dart

I am trying to follow the automated test procedure described here:
http://blog.damondouglas.me/2013/07/unit-testing-in-dart-using-hop-and.html

The code compiles, the test runs from the DART Editor correctly.

I downloaded content_shell (content_shell-windows-ia32-release.zip) from 
[http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/latest/dartium][1]

and unzipped it to a separate folder that is on my PC's path.

When I try to run

```
context_shell --dump-render-tree web\headless_test.html
```

context_shell crashes:

> [5960:5128:0318/145742:23175711:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(734)]
>   Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU().

Advise, please.

Yuri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a discussion about the exactly same error. 
Seems to be a bug http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/68621/

This seems similar https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337116
it was fixed on Jan 23 but Dartium is always a little behind.

Comment: Thank you. That explains it. Is there any way to track the fix progress?

Comment: You can file a bug in dartbug.com then you should get notified (not very reliable on bugs not fixed by the Dart itself though). Probably the only reliable way is to try after each Dart update.

Comment: got this one today `[7516:8216:0522/004346:25691523:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(735)] Ch
eck failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU().`